# Add specific image and title to Facebook sharing link dynamically in react js and Next js Application

Tags: reactjs, facebook, next.js, socialshare

My react js web application contains a dynamic list of articles and I am trying to share the current link (which is article details page) on Facebook.I've spent an hours to find a way to send/share an image but did not found the proper solution using which I can share Images and Title of article along with Link.
anyone have an idea ?
Please suggest me some example links or ideas to implement this in my react js application.

Answer (score 2):

Any Link you share MUST have OG tags in the initial HTML source. Dynamic Tags are not possible, Facebook ignores JavaScript. With Next.js, you can use [SSR (Server Side Rendering)](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering) to avoid this. Every article must have a static URL with specific OG tags.

Alternatively, you can use https://prerender.io/ for this. But since you are using Next.js already, i would rather go for a custom server with SSR.